# getSupportActionBar() The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type TaskActivity. Why?

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I was recommended to extend my Activity class from ActionBarActivity

Here is the previous code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;  

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         
}
```

I wrote new application and followed advice.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;            

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

          @Override
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            ActionBar actionBar =getSupportActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);            
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
          }

          @Override
          public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
          }            
        }
```

If I use ACtionBarActivity instead of Activity, I get the following error on the phone, when I try to run it:

> The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type TaskActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer of my question.
I've asked that again with some remarks.
[How to add support libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891622/how-to-add-support-libraries)

Comment: Does that make this question a duplicate?

Answer (score 79):

Your class needs to extend from [`ActionBarActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html), rather than a plain `Activity` in order to use the `getSupport*()` methods.

**Update** [2015/04/23]: With [the release of Android Support Library 22.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html), you should now extend `AppCompatActivity.` Also, you no longer *have* to extend `ActionBarActivity` or `AppCompatActivity`, as you can now incorporate an [`AppCompatDelegate`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatDelegate.html) instance in any activity.

Comment: @jj_: Well, because the `getSupport*()` methods simply don't exist in `Activity`, but rather live in `FragmentActivity`, which is an extension of the former and an ancestor of `ActionBarActivity`. If that doesn't make sense, just look up the JavaDoc and methods of each class.

Comment: AppCompatActivity brings whole new range of issues.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another solution you could have used. It is working in my app.

```
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar =getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);            
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Then you can get rid of that import for the one line ActionBar use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I've already solved my problem. I've read about adding support libraries.

Comment: Why 5 upvotes for this?  It's not a solution to Activity not having a getSupportActionBar() method, it's just a comment about code style...

Answer (score 3):

If you are already extending from ActionBarActivity and you are trying to get the action bar from a fragment:

```
ActionBar mActionBar = (ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are extending from an AppCompatActivity and are trying to get the ActionBar from the Fragment, you can do this:

```
ActionBar mActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the extends Activity to extends 
AppCompactActivity then try set and getSupportActionBar()

Answer (score 0):

Can you set the ActionBar before you set the Contient View?  This order would be better:

```
 @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar =getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);            
  }
```