# getSupportActionBar error during android tutorial

Tags: android

Until now, I was able to solve the problems I faced with Google search, but I can't actually find any possible solutions to this problem.

(People say something about SherlockActivity but I think these are irrelevant with mine, since that looks like independent API or library)

I assume it's about library import, but I'm not sure what to fix.

The error code prints:
The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type DisplayMessageActivity

on code:
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

and I added the "android-support-v7-appcompat" library to my project and I assured that 1. it's a library 2. it's in the same physical location 3. Yes there is a green tick.

like following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAWWM.jpg

and the build path of my library is set as follows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEX7I.jpg

If you know how to fix it, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution: [getSupportActionBar() The method getSupportActionBar() is undefined for the type TaskActivity. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893161/getsupportactionbar-the-method-getsupportactionbar-is-undefined-for-the-type)

Your class needs to extend from ActionBarActivity, rather than a plain Activity in order to use the getSupport*() methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I saw that post, but I only read the green-ticked answer. After changing public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity to public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity, problem was solved.