# Imagen inc_launcher don´t appear in my application

Tags: android, android-toolbar

In that part of my archive in android paste the following code solved in the thread =>

Actionbar home/app icon is not visible in android lolipop

I´m new in Android.

But I have the following code

```
package com.example.cursoandroid.holamundo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

I´ve import android.app.actionBar, if I´ve ActionBarActivity. But ActionBarActivity haven´t any method: ActionBarActivity.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

I realize the following change. But the inc_launcher don´t appear

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try to use getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true); before `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)`?

Comment: Whats your target version for this App?  If it is pre 11 you need to include some information in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

should be before

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

also support libraries in L have to be properly imported
 see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17993986/4197344

Comment: I make the changes but does not appear the inc_launcher.png in my application. What could I made more?

Comment: This answer is not accurate.  This is not required in any way.  See the docs here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html