# Actionbar sherlock items not showing up

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I followed the steps according to the their official website. Still it doesn't show up items on the actionbar. I also updated the theme name on manifest file.
Any help?

Comment: Older devices doesn't support actionbar!

Comment: have you seen v7 support lib?

Comment: Can you help with actionbarsherlock ?

Comment: see this link also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893161/getsupportactionbar-the-method-getsupportactionbar-is-undefined-for-the-type

Answer (score 0):

Your question is so general but I think you need to change your menu xmls. They are under `res/menu`. If the name of your class is main, then menu should be in `menu_main.xml`. You should change `app:showAsAction` to `ifRoom` or `always`.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="always" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_important" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Error:(4) No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.rampageapp'

Comment: can u help with this ?

Comment: you may also need to add `android:showAsAction="always"`