# How do you ensure resources (e.g. styles) of a support library project (e.g. android-support-v7-appcompat), are added to your project?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am trying to implement the actionbarcompat support library project in my android application and I have followed the guidelines  [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) from the android website on how to implement these but the resources of the support library still are not available to my project. 
Note: I am able to use methods defined from the compiled classes of the library project, I just don't know how to reference from the styles.
I am using eclipse IDE.
Anybody with an idea how or what I am doing wrong please assist me.

Comment: `@style/Theme.AppCompat` should work provided everything is set up correctly. Edit your question to include the IDE as well (I have set it up in Eclipse).

Comment: I tried using that style and even these @sytle/Theme.AppCompat.Light, @sytle/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar but the issue is that these  styles are still not available to my project. And yes I have followed all guidelines from the android site

Comment: Keep in mind that is is `style` not `sytle`. I followed the instructions posted on a new workspace, with a new library project and new application project. Everything worked as expected. Check the `problems` tab to see if there are any issues.

Comment: Oh sorry that was a typo, then I copy-pasted it, its not the problem. The error I get when I try to use one of these styles is: Resource not found that matches the given "names". I think the resources of the support library project haven't been added to my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I happen to have found my own mistake! Most certainly I know a few others might go the same path.

These are the steps in adding a support library with resources.

1. Select File > Import.
2. Select Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next.
3. Browse to the SDK installation directory and then to the Support Library folder /extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/.
4. Click Finish to import the project. You should now see a new project titled android-support-v7-appcompat.
5. In the new library project, expand the libs/ folder, right-click each .jar file and select Build Path > add both the
   android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files to
   the build path.
   6.Right-click the project and select Build Path > Configure Build Path.
   7.In the Order and Export tab, check the .jar files you just added to the build path, so they are available to projects that depend on
   this library project. The appcompat project requires you to export
   both the android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar
   files. Uncheck Android Dependencies.
   8.Click OK to complete the changes.

Now You add the library project to your application:

1. In the Project Explorer, right-click your project and select Properties.
2. In the Library pane, click Add.

   - here is where I went wrong. Check if you've done it the right way too (As shown)

[image: Library Pane]

3. Select the library project and click OK. The appcompat project should be listed as android-support-v7-appcompat.
4. In the properties window, click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the "Adding libraries with resources" section of this document

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Basically, you import the resources in a library project called "android-support-v7-appcompat" that you reference in your app project.

Comment: Thanks Sheldon. I've found out what the problem was. I did not add the library to my project correctly.

Comment: I know. That's what I said !

Comment: Thanks again, check my answer, I misinterpreted part 2 of adding the support library project to my app

Comment: Why would I want to check your answer ? I know the answer - I specified it correctly. Stack Overflow has a Q and A format. By writing my answer in your Question you are just confusing the issue.

Comment: Ok, I'll put changes in that effect.