# Adding Android AppCompat ActionBar from Support Library

Tags: android, adt, android-appcompat

I have problem I can't resolve second day with ActionBar from support library. I tried many times using developer documentation and of course answers from here, such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928610/how-do-you-ensure-resources-e-g-styles-of-a-support-library-project-e-g-and/17931601#17931601)

I can extend ActionBarActivity in my activity java code, but I cant use styles in AndroidManifest.xml. I should use for example android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light", but there is error: no resource found.

First problem in library pane:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpJ9K.jpg

Not resource found in Manifest:
http://img96.imageshack.us/img96/6106/7l8z.jpg

I really try hard to make it work, but I can't handle it by myself.

[edit] I added Support7Demos sample project and there is the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and I guessed it was something about file permission, because my project is also on drive D: and appcompat in c:\program files, so instead of simply importing the appcompat project to my workspace I also checked to copy files to the workspace and the whole project was copied to D:. This solved the problem for me.

Comment: Indeed, that solution works for me too. Project and appcompat library should be on the same partition to make it works.