# appcompat_v7 library error in eclipse when create new application

Tags: android

[image]I am working with eclipse juno and when i create new application so it contain error.
I am go through with following solution but still the error is there.
1. clean and build the application
2.Add the appcompat_v7 library 
please help me to fix this error.![I have added and clean the project but still the error are there][2]  [2]:

Comment: do you need appcompact library reference in your project?

Comment: Do a project > clean. If errors still persist then show what resource is not found (can't tell from your screenshot).

Comment: its normally are not mandatory. you have to remove the appcompact and  change the theme of your project in styles.xml

Comment: hi vandana if you dont need appcompat library u can avoid this by removing style.xml file in values-v11 and values-v14 folders in res. Also remove the library from project properties thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do as directed:

1. Delete `appcompat_v7 library` library from your project. You will find some errors in your main project.
2. You will find errors in your `styles` files in the `values` folder.

(i) Apply the following lines of code in the `styles.xml` of your `values` folder which contains error:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

(ii) Apply these in `styles.xml` of `values-v11` folder:

```
<resources>

        <!--
            Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
            AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
        -->
        <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
            <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
        </style>

    </resources>
```

(iii) Apply these in `styles.xml` of `values-v14` folder:

```
<resources>

            <!--
                Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
                AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
            -->
            <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
                <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
            </style>

        </resources>
```

3. Inside `menu` folder, replace `app:showAsAction="never"` with `android:showAsAction="never"`
4. Finally in your `MainActivity` replace `ActionBarActivity` with `Activity`. Remove all the unnecessary imports.

Now hopefully, your project is ready to run.

Answer (score 0):

That is may be because you are not added the appcompact_v7 support jar file  to your project properly.Check this link [How to add support libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891622/how-to-add-support-libraries.it) will be helpfull.dont forget to restat your eclipse after adding the jar file.

1)add your support library to your project explorer.
2)add jar file inside it to your android project,as suggested in the above link.
3)clean and build your project(or restart eclipse).

Comment: I have add the appcompat_v7 library but the error are still there.

Comment: picture shows that your support library also contains error?Can you please clean it and please report if any error exist